# Костровый или костровой?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фонетика

Знаю, что в походах человек, отвечающий за разведение и поддержание костра, называется "костровой". А вот как быть, если речь идет, например, о чайнике? Чайник будет тоже костровой или все-таки костровый?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слову "костер" соответствуют два относительных прилагательных: кострОвый и менее употребительное слово "костёрный".

Соответственно, чайник кострОвый.

В то же время существует существительное мужского рода "костровОй" - тот, кто поддерживает костёр. Назначить костровым.